# Workday REST API Endpoint Help Needed

Tags: api, rest, workday-api

I'm able to get an access token from workday, but I'm having trouble with understanding the resource endpoints.  I've not been able to get any of the following to work.  The ID I'm using does exist in the tenant.

ONE - this workday article, https://community.workday.com/articles/665624, says REST API URLs must follow this path format:
*(basepath)/api/(service)/(version)/(tenant)/(resource)*

my request - https://(domain)/ccx/api/customerAccounts/v1/(tenant)/customers/(id) --> 404 not found

TWO - The swagger file for customers says the base URL is:
*https://(tenant hostname)/customerAccounts/v1*

my request - https://(domain)/ccx/customerAccounts/v1/customers/(id) --> 404 not found

THREE - The rest client configuration says the Rest endpoint is: *https://(domain)/ccx/api/v1/(tenant)*

my request - https://(domain)/ccx/api/v1/(tenant)/customerAccounts/v1/customers/(id) --> 404 not found

Does anyone know what the URL endpoints should look like?  A specific example would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to do a SAML implementation - using WD as an authenticator? Sorry - if you tell us what type of end point you are calling - maybe I can try to help.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using JWT Assertion to authenticate.  The resources I'm trying to connect to are standard Customer Accounts.  GET method

Comment: Hi, were you able to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Format is as follows.  My issue appears be security related.
Am still having issues here with standard objects.
https://(domain)/ccx/api/customerAccounts/v1/(tennant)/customers/(ID)

for custom objects.  this is confirmed to work.
https://(domain)/ccx/api/v1/(tennant)/customObjects/(objectAlias)/(ID)